# Anchor a GameObject on different points in sprite animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Consider a 2D character holding a torch and a Light object that simulates the light emitted by the fire. This character have different animation clips in which the torch position is different from one another. The animations is a set f slices of the same sprite sheet.

[image]

I want the Light game object to follow the torch fire in the sprite. **Is it possible to set a reference/anchor point in each slice of the sprite to indicate that this should be the position of the torch or lock it in place somehow? Is there a different solution to the problem?**

I tried solving the problem by manually setting the position of the Light per animation frame (on a keyframe). The problem is that if the character is looking to the left, I have to flip these positions. I am guessing that I could create a parent GameObject to wrap it, but it seems hacky.

Comment: What is your animation? Is it the set of sprites or it is some mesh transformations using Spine?

Comment: It is a set of sprites. I just updated the question to include this info.

Comment: Actually, I think that your current approach with the switching frames along with the position of the torch, is the best one in this case. Also, some container object also looks like a fine and easy solution. 

Another option is to use Spine, there you will be able to create "bone" gameobject in the hierarchy, which will change its position. But it not an easy fix =)